# I wonder why I cannot view other users' answers to my question?

Tags: support, answers

I posted a question on Stack Overflow and I wonder why I cannot view the two answers other users posted for me?

[How to integrate KCFinder with TinyMCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41197355/how-to-integrate-kcfinder-with-tinymce)

Why do I have to wait until I get 2k reputation, which will be a long time?

Is there any other method to view the answers?

Comment: Unless the answers were deleted there is *no* limitation in seeing answers.

Answer (score 8):

You have asked [5 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7276226/david?tab=questions), of those, two have received one answer each and the other three (including the one you linked to) have never gotten any answers.

None of the answers you have received has been deleted and are therefore visible to everyone.

So, specifically to your questions:

> I wonder why I cannot view the two answers other users posted for me?

You can, as so can everyone else, so your premise is completely incorrect.

> Why do I have to wait until I get 2k reputation, which will be a long time?

Again, you don't need to. Where did you get the idea that this is the case?

> Is there any other method to view the answers?

Go to questions that have actually been answered.

Answer (score 6):

There are **no** deleted answers on that question (or any other question by you), and you would need [10,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (not 2,000) to see them if they *were* there. There has been a [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338731/view-deleted-answers-on-your-own-questions) to view deleted answers on your own question (regardless of your reputation) but it has not been well-received.

The answers might be given in *comments* rather than answers, which were deleted later. Normal users cannot see deleted comments, even with high reputation. Only ♦ moderators can see those.

Comment: I wonder why the answer is protected by reps.  Is it because of the high level users who gives answer to my questions?  I only have 11 reps.  it will takes forever until I can view the answer, is there any other way to see or get the answer ?

Comment: @David I do have the reputation to see deleted answers, but there are none on your question. You must have seen them in another question, but not this one.

Comment: Perhaps I just have to wait until I get the real answer.  If anyone can help me get answer to my questions please help.  thanks.

Comment: @David you have been given a real answer, and it's correct, please don't dismiss people's answer so quickly

Comment: @Ramhound He means a real answer on his SO question, not this Meta.SE question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are talking about answers which have been deleted, there is never a case where you, another user, or even a viewer, cannot see an answer on your question, irrespective of your reputation.

However, not every question has an answer posted.